# Serialize enum field into JSON in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I've got a stupid question that stunned me a bit.
I have an enum and a data class like this:

```
enum class MyEventType(val typeName: String) {
    FIRST("firstEventReceived")
}

data class MyEvent(
    val id: String,
    val event: MyEventType
)
```

I need to send this as a json string, but common desearilizer makes such a json

```
{ 
    "id": "identifier",
    "event": "FIRST"
}
```

but i need

```
{ 
    "id": "identifier",
    "event": "firstEventReceived"
}
```

As far as i understand, kotlin allows to override getter in data class, but i didn't succeed in it... Trying to make

```
data class MyEvent(
    val id: String
) {
    val event: MyEventType get() event.typeName
}
```

but i've missed something, i guess...

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to annotate the property with [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html):

```
enum class MyEventType(@JsonValue val typeName: String) {
    FIRST("firstEventReceived")
}

data class MyEvent(
    val id: String,
    val event: MyEventType
)


fun main() {
    MyEvent(id = "foo", event = MyEventType.FIRST)
        .let { jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(it) }
        .let { println(it) }
}
```

Prints:

```
{"id":"foo","event":"firstEventReceived"}
```

Answer (score 12):

For ["Kotlin Serialization"](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library, you can use the `@SerialName` annotation:

```kotlin
@Serializable
enum class ConnectionStatus {

    @SerialName("open")
    OPEN,
    
    @SerialName("connecting")
    CONNECTING,
    
    @SerialName("closed")
    CLOSED
}
```

Comment: Note that enum should be annotated `@Serializable` to work with `@SerialName`

Comment: @Query("type") type: Type
but cant serilizer

Comment: In my case I don't use `@Serializable` for `enum`, but for some cases it should be used. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to annotate the `typeName` with `@JsonValue`. This will serialize and deserialize the enum field as you want.

```
enum class MyEventType(@JsonValue val typeName: String) {
    FIRST("firstEventReceived");
}
```

An alternative is to use `@JsonFormat` (if you are using jackson version < 2.9);

```
enum class MyEventType(@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT) val typeName: String) {
    FIRST("firstEventReceived");
}
```

Here's an example;

```
  @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
        val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(MyEvent("1", MyEventType.FIRST))
        println(json)

        val event = mapper.readValue<MyEvent>(json)
        println(event)
    }
```

You get the output;

```
{"id":"1","event":"firstEventReceived"}
MyEvent(id=1, event=FIRST)
```

I used Jackson version 2.12.0. Here's a good read on enum manipulation with Jackson - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums

Comment: You can use the Kotlin extension to deserialize: `val event = mapper.readValue<MyEvent>(json)`.

Comment: I see, the extension means `jackson-module-kotlin`? I am not sure only with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)`, it can deserialise. It fails due to the type mismatch.

Comment: Yes, the [`readValue()`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/2.13/src/main/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/Extensions.kt#L39) function from `jackson-module-kotlin` uses type inference so you don't need to provide the `MyEvent::class.java` argument. `@JsonFormat` is not a good choice for this use case anyway, as it serializes the whole enum including the property name.

Comment: Actually, good point on applying @JsonFormat on the enum. Updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For GSON users, you can use the @SerializedName annotation:

```
enum class ConnectionStatus {

    @SerializedName("open")
    OPEN,
    
    @SerializedName("connecting")
    CONNECTING,
    
    @SerializedName("closed")
    CLOSED
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can have **enum with 2+ fields** which you want to be serialized

```
enum class MyEventType(
        val firstField: String,
        val secondField: String,
        val thirdField: String
) {
        MY_ENUM("firstFieldValue", "secondFieldValue", "thirdFieldValue")
}
```

You can chose one of the following two options:

1. Put **@JsonValue over a method**(lets call it getter) that will return the required value(*if you need only part of the fields*):

   ```
   @JsonValue
   fun getSerializedObject(): String {
           return "{firstField: $firstField, thirdField: $thirdField}"
   }
   ```

   Result will be `"{firstField: firstFieldValue, thirdField: thirdFieldValue}"`
2. Put **@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT) over your enum** class(for serialization class as common class):

   ```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
    enum class MyEventType(
            val firstField: String,
            val secondField: String,
            val thirdField: String
    ) {
            MY_ENUM("firstField", "secondField", "thirdField")
    }
   ```

   Result will be `"{"firstField": "firstFieldValue", "secondField": "secondFieldValue", "thirdField": "thirdFieldValue"}"`